# Tor browser user-agent strings

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, browsers, fingerprinting

What is the current user-agent string(s) of the Tor browser?
What user-agent strings has the Tor browser (and older Tor software) used in the past?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tor browser user-agent strings at this point in time Dec-31-2014 for the current version is:

***Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0***

In the past Tor browser has used many different user-agent strings, depending on which version of Tor browser you are interested in, one can search for that particular user-agent string.

Comment: Where can I search for the user-agent strings?

Comment: @user194 Dear user194, You should run the version of Tor browser you are interested in, and while runing it use the following site to analyze it for you. Not only you obtain the user-agent, but also a lot more information about Tor browser.  http://ip-check.info/?lang=en    Warm Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The current (2019-09-19) user-agent of Tor is

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0

Source: https://blog.torproject.org/browser-fingerprinting-introduction-and-challenges-ahead

Answer (score 0):

Tor Browser on GNU/Linux 64-bit

---

> Tor Browser 9.5.3 (based on Mozilla Firefox 68.11.0esr) (64-bit)

---

User Agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0
```

Answer (score 0):

User-Agents

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.100 YaBrowser/16.11.1.673 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 YaBrowser/17.6.0.1633 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36 OPR/43.0.2442.806 (Edition Yx)
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 YaBrowser/17.1.0.2034 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.100 YaBrowser/16.11.1.673 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36 OPR/42.0.2393.94
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; thl T9 Build/MRA58K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.85 Mobile Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SM-G925I Build/MMB29K; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Mobile Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Redmi Note 3 Build/MMB29M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Mobile Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1; Micromax Q334 Build/LMY47I) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Mobile Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; PowerFive Build/LRX21M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Mobile Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; MFLogin3T Build/KTU84P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; MFLogin3T Build/KTU84P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.135 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; TZ707 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; 9005X Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.2; LG-E455 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.91 Mobile Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.2; LG-E455 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 YaBrowser/16.10.2.1487.00 Mobile Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A405 Safari/7534.48.3
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 5.0; Mobile; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Mozilla/5.0 () AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393
```